# How do I tell what syntax file is being used?

Tags: vim

Vim is syntax highlighting my file in a funny way, and I want to know what syntax file is responsible for this behaviour. How do I find out what syntax files vim has loaded?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

To find out which files Vim has actually loaded, execute

```
:scriptnames
```

Comment: That's useful. Now, here is something I'm not sure about: if a syntax file shows up in this list, is it guaranteed that the syntax file is "active"? I can see quite a few syntax files here.

Comment: Generally, only the last one listed is "active", and even it may not be if you've turned syntax highlighting off. To see the syntax currently in effect, execute `:echo b:current_syntax`. To see the syntax items currently in effect, do as Ingo suggested and execute `:syntax list`. The latter may help if syntax items from more than one syntax file are in effect, as Ingo noted.

Comment: On Mac OS X I modified the `/usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim`. After using the above command I realized it was using MacVim's version at `~/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/filetype.vim`. If you have MacVim installed, make sure you modify the correct file.

Comment: You may have two syntax files loaded that have the same name.  For example, vim ships with syntax highlighting for ColdFusion, (`/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/cf.vim` for me).  I installed a custom cf.vim because the standard one is dated.  `:scriptnames` shows both files.  The default is lower on the script list; however, the former is being used.  If you look at `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/cf.vim`, there's a guard `if exists("b:current_syntax") finish endif`.  So, in my case, the `scriptnames` was helpful, but I had to dig a bit deeper.

Answer (score 67):

The syntax for the current buffer can be queried via

```
:setlocal syntax?
```

It usually (but not necessarily) corresponds to the buffer's filetype (`:setlocal filetype?`).

For a deeper look,

```
:syntax list
```

shows all syntax definitions (some syntaxes (can) include other language's syntaxes, e.g. `java` has `html` for the JavaDoc comment markup).

Comment: This is what I came looking for based on the title of OP's question. OP of course clarifies in the description he's looking for the actual syntax file, but I appreciate you leaving this here since it's one of the first answers in search engines.

Answer (score 9):

You can view what filetype(s) are currently used and by

```
:verbose set ft ?
```

The plugin handling the filetype is most likely located at

```
:e $VIMRUNTIME\ftplugin
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you would like to know exactly which highlighting color scheme(syntax) is currently being used for the file opened, here is what I do:

as @garyjohn mentioned

```
:scriptnames
```

But this will show you a complete list of settings currently loaded.

```
  1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
  2: ~/.vimrc
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
 11: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 14: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
 15: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 16: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
 17: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 18: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 19: ~/.vim/syntax/applescript.vim
```

Then which exactly is the one doing coloring? => the last one always the decision maker(e.g.):

`~/.vim/syntax/applescript.vim`

In my case, I want to test last downloaded syntax of applescript.vim if working.

On the other side, please be reminded that vim syntax is filetype/extension-based, so check exactly the file definition at `/usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim`, there you can easily find out AppleScript has its unique extension defined as `.scpt` (as standard) .

Hope this helps also.